# Horizontally 'collapse' two columns with matching substrings into one

Tags: sql-server-2008

My query results in a table that looks like this:

```
Unit25  Unit26  Seconds25  Seconds26
A2501   null     383042     null
A2502   A2602    354554     35147
A2503   A2603    344021     33388
A2504   null     359453     null
A2505   null     16702      null
A2507   null     14784      null
null    A2608    null       16997
A2509   A2609    13092      358893
null    A2610    null       291256
A2511   A2611    18770      369082
A2512   A2612    8647       null
A2513   null     65214      null
```

A25s are matched to corresponding A26s by a substring of their last two digits. 
However, I would like to combine those A25 and A26 columns into something like this:

```
Unit    TotalSeconds
01       383042
02       389701
03       377409
04       359453
05       16702
07       14784
08       16997
09       371985
10       291256
11       387852
12       8647
13       65214
```

I can get TotalSeconds by using ISNULL to turn those nulls into 0s and adding Seconds25 and Seconds26 together, but I'm not so sure how to turn Unit25 and Unit26 into one column of substrings. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Coalesce (or isnull) the two columns together so you always get a value, it doesn't matter which one. Get the length of the data, and then substring the last two characters, getting two characters starting at length -1. Eg - "A2501" is length five, so you want to substring from position 4 to get 01.

```
SUBSTRING(Coalesce(Unit25, Unit26), Len(Coalesce(Unit25, Unit26)) - 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
select substring(Coalesce(unit25,unit26),4,2) as units,isnull(seconds25,0)+isnull(seconds26,0) from @t
```